# Looking for a way to use voice commands create calendar entry in non-Google calendar

Tags: calendar, voice-command

I'm looking for a way to create calendar entries in a non-Google calendar using voice commands. The built in voice command (using CM11 M8 / 4.4.4 with Google apps) only creates entries in my Google calendar and I do not see an option to change this behavior. I'm happy to use a different voice command app if that's what's necessary.

To clarify: I would like to create this calendar entry in a calendar hosted on a server accessed by caldav.

Comment: I think you need a calendar app that uses the same intent for creating Calendar apps.

Answer (score 0):

While strictly speaking, app recommendations are off-topic here – let's tread it as "how can I do that". And as this is my second question today, it's time for the app which answers every second question here: [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), optionally with the [AutoVoice](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.joaomgcd.autovoice) addon for more convenience and flexibility.

The [Tasker UserGuide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html) explains:

> **Calendar Insert:**
>   Insert an entry into the specified calendar.

(More details there)

With AutoVoice, you can have a widget/shortcut on your homescreen to activate it (or have *Tasker* do so via some other event, e.g. "shaking the device up-down twice"). Then speak your command, and *Tasker* would execute the Task assigned to what it recognizes. There are tutorials around also explaining how to make a "loop" for the "Sorry, I didn't understand – please repeat!" case ;)

Drawbacks: Both apps come with a fee if you want to really use them. *Tasker* has a 7-day-trial at their homepage, *AutoVoice* has a limited "free version" – so you at least have a chance to check first if it meets your requirements. Will take a few days getting used to *Tasker* – but once you did, you will wonder how you could do without ☺